# Sort line based on the value of a column

Tags: shell-script, shell, sort

I have to sort a thread dump which looks like this:

```
$ jstack -l 5213 | grep cpu 

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 cpu=2.21ms elapsed=478.03s tid=0x00000000013bb800 nid=0x1465 waiting on condition  [0x00007f386cc0c000]
"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 cpu=1.30ms elapsed=478.03s tid=0x00000000013c6000 nid=0x1466 in Object.wait()  [0x00007f386cb0b000]
"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0.31ms elapsed=478.03s tid=0x00000000013db000 nid=0x1467 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=3042.89ms elapsed=478.02s tid=0x00000000013dd800 nid=0x1468 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
"C1 CompilerThread0" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=1840.51ms elapsed=478.02s tid=0x00000000013e0000 nid=0x1469 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
```

The dump is pretty big so I'd like to sort it by the column "cpu" (either ascending or descending). It seems the sort command accepts the "k" parameter to indicate the column to used as criteria for sorting. "cpu" is the 5th column, so I've tried with:

```
$ jstack -l 5213 | grep cpu | sort -k 5
"ServerService Thread Pool -- 1" #26 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=10.86ms elapsed=753.24s tid=0x0000000002b68800 nid=0x1482 waiting on condition  [0x00007f385c33b000]
"Transaction Expired Entry Monitor" #131 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0.48ms elapsed=751.66s tid=0x00000000082ed000 nid=0x14eb in Object.wait()  [0x00007f3853826000]
"Transaction Reaper Worker 0" #133 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0.13ms elapsed=751.63s tid=0x00000000084d9000 nid=0x14ee in Object.wait()  [0x00007f3853523000]
```

I see the order has changed yet it does not follow the criteria I'd expect ("cpu"). Any idea if a text like "cpu=value" can be used as criteria to sort or it needs to be combined with other commands?
Thanks

Comment: Is the CPU unit always in `ms` or it could be in `s` also?

Comment: I see it's in ms also for thousands (3042.89ms)......

Comment: If you try `sort  -k5 file | column -t` you will see why. `sort` breaks fields on whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a design "pattern" that can be adopted, while sorting whole lines on a subset of input, which by itself cannot be directly retrieved. In such cases, doing this in a multi-stage pipeline like below would be better than writing a full-fledged command in Awk or perl

One way you could do is use Awk to extract the `ms` substring, convert into a numeric  and print the whole line and the millisecond value and sort based on the latter and trim it out afterwards.

Pipe your command output to the following

```bsh
awk 'match($0, /cpu=[[:digit:].]+/){print substr($0, RSTART+4, RLENGTH-1)+0, $0}' | 
sort -n -k1,1 | 
cut -d' ' -f2-
```

For descending order of times, add the `-r` flag to `sort`

Comment: Thanks! awesome hack!

Comment: This is known as a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `=` as the field separator, the cpu value is in the 4th field. You can do

```bsh
jstack -l 5213 | grep cpu | sort -t '=' -g -k4,4
```

with `-g` for "general numeric" sort.

With given data, output is

```
"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0.31ms elapsed=478.03s tid=0x00000000013db000 nid=0x1467 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 cpu=1.30ms elapsed=478.03s tid=0x00000000013c6000 nid=0x1466 in Object.wait()  [0x00007f386cb0b000]
"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 cpu=2.21ms elapsed=478.03s tid=0x00000000013bb800 nid=0x1465 waiting on condition  [0x00007f386cc0c000]
"C1 CompilerThread0" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=1840.51ms elapsed=478.02s tid=0x00000000013e0000 nid=0x1469 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=3042.89ms elapsed=478.02s tid=0x00000000013dd800 nid=0x1468 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
```

This assumes the equal sign does not appear in the quoted string, so it's not as stable as @Inian's answer.